# Invalid token or signature - when starting a workflow

Tags: workflow, oauth

We configured the workflow service in our SharePoint 2019 farm using HTTP. When the workflow starts it failed with "HTTP Unauthorized" error coming from WFE server. The WFE server presents the following details for that error:

```
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Read Token
Could not validate security key identifier clause. KeyIdentifierClause: 'X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0x353A22F383B5A88460DBBB4758B6FD8015BB6E72)'.
Could not validate security key identifier. KeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier(IsReadOnly = False, Count = 1, Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0x353A22F383B5A88460DBBB4758B6FD8015BB6E72))'.
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Invalid token or signature. Exception: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: Invalid JWT token. Could not resolve issuer token.     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ReadTokenCore(String token, Boolean isActorToken)  at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TryExtractAndValidateToken(HttpContext httpContext, SPIncomingTokenContext& tokenContext, SPIdentityProofToken& identityProofToken)
```

We already tried running "Refresh Trusted Security Token Services Metadata feed", but didn't work.

How can we resolve this error?

Comment: After following all the steps and guidelines from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx the issue came down to restarting the "Refresh Trusted Security Token Services Metadata feed" Timer job from the Central Admin